# Character encoding problems after downloading from Filezilla

Tags: windows, ftp, encoding, filezilla

I have been using FileZilla for a while and I realized that when I download files from the server using FTP it encodes/changes some files making them useless to upload to a new server.

I tried forcing FileZilla to "UTF-8" but it did not work.

I need to configure windows to avoid encoding my files so I can upload them back to a new server.

Any solution?

Comment: Instead of using text transfer modes you should switch to binary transfer, then the files won't change on download.